# Angular ag-grid not working

Tags: angular, search, filter, ag-grid

I have an ag-grid which is rendering table from a .json file and searching is done using quick filter. The search term is displayed in the form of angular material chip below the filter.

I'm struggling with to reload the ag-grid to its default state if we  close the  chip which is displaying search results and also to include multiple filters in it using the chip.

Here is my sample code, but I'm struggling with setting it up.

HTML-

```
<div class="container">
<mat-form-field class="demo-chip-list"  *ngIf="gridApi">              
<mat-chip-list #chipList>
<div style="width:100%; margin-left:10%;"><label><span class="search-button">Search Funds</span></label><input class="search-input"  
[ngModel]="filterText"(ngModelChange)="gridApi.setQuickFilter($event)" [matChipInputFor]="chipList"
[matChipInputSeparatorKeyCodes]="separatorKeysCodes"                   [matChipInputAddOnBlur]="addOnBlur"                     (matChipInputTokenEnd)="add($event)" /></div><br/><div style="width:100%; margin-left:10%;"><mat-chip *ngFor="let fruit of fruits" [selectable]="selectable" 
                      [removable]="removable" (click)="onGridReady(params)" (remove)="remove(fruit)">
               {{fruit.name}}
<mat-icon matChipRemove *ngIf="removable"  ><sup>x</sup></mat-icon></mat-chip></div></mat-chip-list></mat-form-field>
<div class="header" style="display:inline"></div><div> <ag-grid-angular 
      style="position:absolute;padding-left:5%; bottom:0px;width: 90%; height: 350px;" #agGrid  id="myGrid" class="ag-fresh" [columnDefs]="columnDefs" [animateRows]="true" [enableRangeSelection]="true" [enableSorting]="true" [enableFilter]="true" [pagination]="true" (gridReady)="onGridReady($event)">
      </ag-grid-angular></div></div>
```

Here is my Component.ts:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import {AgGridModule} from "ag-grid-angular";
import { GridOptions } from 'ag-grid/main';
import { HttpClient } from "@angular/common/http";
import {NgModel} from '@angular/forms';
import { MatChipInputEvent } from '@angular/material';
import {ENTER, COMMA} from '@angular/cdk/keycodes';
import "ag-grid-enterprise";
@Component({
  selector: 'app-funds-table',
  templateUrl: './funds-table.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./funds-table.component.css']
})

export class FundsTableComponent implements OnInit {

  visible: boolean = true;
  selectable: boolean = true;
  removable: boolean = true;
  addOnBlur: boolean = true;

  // Enter, comma
  separatorKeysCodes = [ENTER, COMMA];

  fruits = [
    { name: 'ABC' }

  ];
  add(event: MatChipInputEvent): void {
    let input = event.input;
    let value = event.value;

    // Add our fruit
    if ((value || '').trim()) {
      this.fruits.push({ name: value.trim() });
    }

    // Reset the input value
    if (input) {
      input.value = '';
    }
  }
  remove(fruit: any): void {
    let index = this.fruits.indexOf(fruit);

    if (index >= 0) {
      this.fruits.splice(index, 1);
    }
  }
  private gridApi;
  private gridColumnApi;
  private columnDefs;
  private filterText = "";
  ngOnInit() {}
constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
    this.columnDefs = [{headerName: "Ticker", field: "Ticker"},
      {headerName: "Id", field: "Id"},
     {headerName: "Utilities", field: "Utilities"}
    ];
  }

onGridReady(params) {
this.gridApi = params.api;
this.gridColumnApi = params.columnApi;
this.http.get("./../assets/fundsData/fund_info.json").subscribe(data => {this.gridApi.setRowData(data);
});
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The code is not nicely displayed, but I can imagine that when you remove the chips, you can set the filterText to '' and make a call to gridColumnApi.setQuickFilter.

setQuickFilter('') would return the raw grid data.